# How update xml file settings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration

I have my own xml settings file in winform app. It is installed on some location. And I need to update this file (add some new atributes/settings) without loosing old settings.

Example old xml setting:

```
<settings>
  <someSetting>Old Value</someSetting>
<settings>
```

Example new xml setting file:

```
 <settings>
   <someSetting>default value</someSettingNew>
   <someSettingNew>defaul value</someSettingNew>
 <settings>
```

I need new xml setting file look after update like this:

```
 <settings>
   <someSetting>Old Value</someSettingNew>
   <someSettingNew>defaul value</someSettingNew>
 <settings>
```

How can I do this in C# .NET Framework 3.5. And I know that I can do this with App.config, but I need my own manager. I need to share this config file between two apps (Settings App for Windows Service and that Windows Service)

Thanx.

UPDATE:
I have to explain my workflow:

1. windows service + app gui is instaled with instalator
2. windows service is configured with app gui
3. i will create update (dll + new xml config file)
4. dll's are deployed, and i need to merge old xml config file with  new config file (new parameters and default value). How do this programmicaly? I want update only xml file, not program code. In windows servic app I can detect update so I can call some procedure to load new settings. Thats what I need, how do this procedure?

Comment: In your update #4 is contradictory: you want a programmatic way, but not code. If you want a programmatic solution then you will need code to implement it. (Note XML can be code, e.g. XSLT, but it is still *code*).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it bad. I meant that I dont want define new updates in old xml in code as Darin wrote. I understand that merging two xml needs to be done by code.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("someSettingNew", "defaul value"));
doc.Save("test.xml");
```